# Can ADLDS LDAP attributes be calculated

Tags: ldap

I have a requirement where I would like an attribute in a user object in AD LDS to be 
the result of a calculation. That is , I would like the attribute to be equal to 
the cn concatenated with @mydomain.com .

Is this possible and if so , do you have any pointers as to how I could achieve this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In short it is possible.

The word calculation suggests that the result is different than the two parts. This is not the case here. You are trying to create a string based on the value of two separate attributes.

How you do it is another question.

We happen to own Dell Quick Connect Express for AD ( I do believe that there used to be a free version somewhere).

What I am able to do for instance is take the GivenName + "." + Surname + '@yourdomain.com" and set it as the mail attribute for an account.

That has been the easiest way to do it. You can also code it but that would be out of my reach.

I am thinking that you can also do this via powershell if you had access to the source content in a delimited format.

Good luck!

Best

Amos

Comment: Hi, I suppose in your case , the value in the AD for mail attribute is not GivenName + "." + Surname + '@yourdomain.com" , its quick connect that returns this computed value to you ? My requirement is that if you query the AD using whichever tool or api, it returns the concatenated value of cn + @mydomain.com.